# iPad/iOS browsing to intranet URL without a ".com"

Tags: ios, web-browsing

I am on my office network, trying to access our Intranet via iOS Safari. Our Intranet URL is http://Intranet/  (no domain or prefix). Safari never opens this. Is there a way to get to this address on an iPad?

Comment: If I browse to http://intranet/, i get a "Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found. I am on the same network as this server.

Comment: does this work from a laptop via WiFi?  Can you connect via the server's IP?

Comment: Are you using wi-fi or 3G/4G?

Comment: @Jason, this works from a laptop via the same wireless network. I can get to the IP.

Comment: @lupincho I am only on wifi

Comment: my best guess is that for some reason the device is unable to resolve the DNS for your server.  If you can hit the IP  it would confirm that theory.  However, if that's the case I'm not sure of how to fix it.  You might try "forgetting" the network on the device, and then reconnecting.

Comment: find the DNS server ip by doing "nslookup intranet" on the laptop, go into network settings on the iPad and see if the DNS server has been correctly configured by DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

I went into Settings > General > Search Domains and entered our domain name and now I can go to http://hostname/

If this is the solution, I guess I need to figure out how to set this setting in DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

add your domain in the wifi or network in settings.
if you click on the wifi that you are connected, you will be able to see the DHCP setting.
Under Search Domains, add your internal fully qualified domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to http://intranet./ (with a dot at the end of the hostname to make it absolute).

Comment: Same thing... looks like I can't get to any host by hostname only. I need the FQDN...

Answer (score 0):

The answer that 'supa' gave was right. I checked my dhcp-server settings and added scope option 15 to push the domainname to clients. If the device was connected in the past you have to clear the 'Searchdomains'-setting. Then back to wifi-settings, when recconnected the setting should be ok. If not, completely erase the wificonnection and reconnect.

If the device was never connected before it works instantly.